# Play Framework joins and the model

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, ebean

This isn't a problem, its more of a "is this the right approach" kind of deal.

So lets say I have a model like this

```
class A extends Model{
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public B;
}

class B extends Model{

   String c;
}
```

Now I want to access all objects of A that have a particular value of c in their B objects.

So should I:

1. Get all objects of B with a certain value c and then find corresponding A's with those objects(if so how, getting confused)
2. Get all objects of A with `find.all()` then look through the list (seems a bad idea as there will be a large amount of A's and not so many B's).

Any help would be appreciated (oh and assume I've written `@Entity` and `@Required` and all the rest appropriately)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1 is the right way to go. You can use a query such as

```
A.find().where().eq("b.id", yourBId).findList();
```

Possibly adding a fetch("b"), if it isn't fetched automatically.

Comment: This works for a `@OneToOne` but for some reason when I use a `@OneToMany` it fails. Any idea why?

Comment: How does it fail? How about with the added fetch, like: A.find.fetch("b").where().eq("b.id", bId).findList();