# Play framework 2 : JOIN between models in Finder

Tags: playframework-2.1, ebean

What I'm looking seems to be answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17449406/play-framework-joins-and-the-model), but I'm unsure to repeat this as I'm not too familiar with JPA.

My situation involves 3 classes : `Role`, `User` and `Pool`, described as follow :

```
public class Role extends Model {
   @Id public Long id;
   public String name;
   // ...
}

public class User extends Model {
   @Id public Long id;
   public string displayName;
   // ...
   @ManyToMany
   public List<Role> roles;
   // ...
}

public class Pool extends Model {
   @Id public Long id;
   public String name;
   // ...
   @ManyToMany
   public List<Role> roles;

   public List<User> getMembers() {
      // ???
   }
}
```

(**Note**: there may also be resource restrictions, or permissions, that could be assigned to users and pools, that could be used to filter in.. or out.. users allowed in a pool.)

I have added a `static` member

```
public static final Finder<Long, User> find = new Finder<Long, User>(Long.class, User.class);
```

to the `Pool` class (that should be used in the `getPoolMembers` method), but I am unsure how to fetch all the users with intersecting groups (and possibly other constraints).

Thank you for helping.

Comment: Is there a Pool field on Users to link the two, or are they linked somehow through Roles?

Comment: Yes, they share the same roles, but, essentially, I don't want any direct relationship between a `Pool` and a `User`; a `User` is part of the pool if it shares any of the same `Role`

Comment: I'm not sure if you can configure Ebean to do that.  I think you'll be better off doing a RawSql query, so you can configure the join's yourself.  I assume your desired query would be something like `select * from User left join Pool on (User.role=Pool.role) where (Pool.id=$id)` where $id is the id of the Pool you call the getPoolMembers method on, right?  I don't have the syntax for Ebean RawSql in front of me, but I'll check for an example...

Answer (score 1):

First, I would move your finder to the User class, that way User.find returns User objects, instead of Pool.find returning Users.

Without a direct link between Users and Pools to do Ebean fetches on, I would suggest using a SqlQuery (I got mixed up between SqlQuery and RawSql in my comment on your OP: Sql Query allows for parameterizing of the queries more easily; RawSql is for when the query is fixed)

The result of the SqlQuery is a collection of SqlRows.  Given these you can map back to Users.

The code would look something like:

```
List<User> = new ArrayList<User>();

SqlQuery query = Ebean.createSqlQuery("select user.id from User left join Pool on (User.role=Pool.role) where (Pool.id=:id)"); // parameter is prefixed by a colon
query.setParameter("id", this.id);

List<SqlRow> rows = query.findList();
for(SqlRow row : rows){
    users.add(User.find.byId(row.getLong("user.id")); // gets the entry from the row for user.id, finds the User corresponding to the id, and then adds the User to the results list
}
```

It's not elegant, but HTH.

Comment: It's a good start! And yes, returning `User`s from `Pool` is a little weird... Thank you for that comment.

Comment: So where do you stand now? I didn't actually create a project to test this code alone, but I put it into an analogous relationship in one of my projects and got the results I expected.  Is it not giving you the results you expect?